# Ajax call not working on enter keypress, works only for click function

Tags: php, forms, function, jquery, keypress

I have a ajax method of calling data from php file, i learned it from one of a blog, now it works file for submit button click function, but when i press `enter` the variables get shown in address bar and ajax process is not executed, Can any one please help me doing it on a press enter method....

This is my code:-

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='search_user_submit']").click(function() {
        var cv = $('#newInput').val();
        var cvtwo = $('input[name="search_option"]:checked').val();
        var data = { "cv" : cv, "cvtwo" : cvtwo }; // sending two variables
        $("#SearchResult").html('<img src="../../involve/images/elements/loading.gif"/>').show();
        var url = "../elements/search-user.php";
        $.post(url, data, function(data) {
            $("#SearchResult").html(data).show();
        });
    });
});
});//]]>  
</script>
```

I have tried it by taking an if condition along with keypress event still its not working:-

```
if (e.keyCode == 13) { // Do stuff }
else { // My above code }
//In this also it seems that i am doing something wrong.
```

Can anybody please enlighten me oh how to do it.

My input field is:-

```
<input type="text" name="searchuser_text" id="newInput" maxlength="255" class="inputbox MarginTop10">
```

My submit button is:-

```
<input class="Button" name="search_user_submit" type="button" value="Search">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `event.preventDefault();` for enter keypress.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you type enter there is executed default onSubmit handler for a form. You can use submit jquery function to handle both enter and click on submit button.

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    var cv = $('#newInput').val();
    var cvtwo = $('input[name="search_option"]:checked').val();
    var data = { "cv" : cv, "cvtwo" : cvtwo }; // sending two variables
    $("#SearchResult").html('<img src="../../involve/images/elements/loading.gif"/>').show();
    var url = "../elements/search-user.php";
    $.post(url, data, function(data) {
        $("#SearchResult").html(data).show();
    });
    return false;
});
```

return false in this function will prevent submit of the form.